# CSS gradient not showing in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

### So when I hover on the image, gradient appears on the image, but it's not working in FireFox.

```
.last-update .content:hover {
    #title {
        display: block;
        animation: fade-in 150ms; 
    }
    .gradient::after {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, #000 100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make it a [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of the browser you might need to use -moz prefix

Here are some examples

```
.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Chrome, Safari 4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

You might also want to look at the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Comment: It seems really unlikely they would be using a version of Firefox that is **over a decade out of date**.